# Catalyst Control Center (CCC) does not save preset

Tags: amd-catalyst

I have defined two presets; one for a three-display unified EyeFinity setup and another one for all three monitors extended.

However, activating the preset for the latter did not trigger any reaction.

I found out what went wrong (see below).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had changed the settings to extended from the Windows level settings and not within CCC itself. CCC can only control settings from its side and not from Windows.

If you cant resolve the issue this way, here are some more candidate solutions:

http://www.overclock.net/t/1287767/ccc-presets-not-working-and-settings-randomly-wont-apply

http://hardforum.com/showthread.php?t=1593733

http://www.rage3d.com/board/showthread.php?t=33977837

Answer (score 0):

1. Hit start and search for device install and click "Change device installation settings."
2. Click the box beside "No, let me choose what to do."
3. Click the box beside "Never install driver software from Windows Update."
4. Save Changes.

Download the AMD Mobility Catalyst Beta for Windows. Install it and let your computer restart.